# CSS :not() not working properly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I have a code structure like this:

```css
.header-container a:not(.header-menu-right a) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header-menu-right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
        <!-- unimportant links -->
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
          <!-- unimportant links -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#">link</a> 
  <!-- important link -->
</div>
```

As you can see by the notes, I only want CSS to change the last a-tag.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and there you go:

```
.header-container > a {
    display:none;
}
```

Thanks!